# How to stream live video from WP7 camera to XNA application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

How I can stream video (live) form my WP7 camera to my XNA project?
Just simple display of camera's capture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THe APIs to enable this are not currently publicly available. Only Microsoft, mobile operators, OEMS and their partners are allowed to do this at the moment.

It is hoped (expected?) that this will become avaialble to all in the future.

Comment: +1 for "hoped". Also to note that some hackers have managed to get this working - http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/11/18/wp7-hack-001-raw-video-feed-and-augmented-reality - so you can do this for your own amusement (not for Marketplace consumption yet)

Comment: Just as I thought, but sometimes I'm wondering why it is so much limited.

Comment: @Paweł Smejda ther are a number of reasons but the big 3 are: 1) the amount of functionality thaat could be written and tested in the time available to get to market; 2) The platform is very strict on security; adn 3) some funcitonltiy is not availabel to all to allow MSFT partners/OEMs/Operators to create apps which can be used as distinguishing features.

Comment: and 4) every WP7 phone actually ships with a built in Kinect - sometime later this year, Microsoft will stun the world by unveiling this functionality.